# Finding the length of one side of a triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

In **$\triangle\,$ABC** if **BC** is unity and $\sin\frac{A}{2} = x_1, \sin\frac{B}{2} = x_2, \cos\frac{A}{2} = x_3, \cos\frac{B}{2} = x_4$ with $$ \left(\frac{x_1}{x_2}\right)^ {2007} - \left(\frac{x_3}{x_4}\right)^{2006} = 0 $$ then the length of **AC** is equal to $\ldots$.

I tried using sine rule and arrive at an expression for **b** but have not been able to do so.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Solving_triangles_by_half-angle_formulae

Comment: tried that but I am not able to simplify s-a and s-b terms in the resulting expression

Comment: Same here. But the first line says:"BC is unity". Again, we need to find the length of $BC?$

Comment: i think this means $$BC=1$$

Comment: are $$A,B,C$$ also unknown?

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee the length of the side BC is 1("BC is unity") and by "b" I refer to the side AC,  the side opposite to the angle B. and sorry AC has to be found. I'll edit the question

Comment: @dr.sonnhard graubner the angles A ,B, and C are not known, however their sines,cosines and tangents can however be calculated in terms of x1,x2,x3 and x4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a given $\triangle$ both $\displaystyle \frac{A}{2},\frac{B}{2}\in\bigg(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg).$

For $x\in(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2})$, $\sin x$ is a strictly increasing function whereas $\cos x$ is a strictly decreasing function.

Now if $\displaystyle \frac{A}{2}>\frac{B}{2}$ then $\displaystyle \sin\frac{A}{2}>\sin\frac{B}{2}$ and $\displaystyle \cos\frac{A}{2}<\cos\frac{B}{2}$. So $x_{1}>x_{2}$ and $x_{3}<x_{4}$.

So $x^{2007}_{1}x^{2006}_{4}=x^{2007}_{2}x^{2006}_{3}$ not possible.

Similarly if  $\displaystyle \frac{A}{2}<\frac{B}{2}$ then $\displaystyle \sin\frac{A}{2}<\sin\frac{B}{2}$ and $\displaystyle \cos\frac{A}{2}>\cos\frac{B}{2}$. So $x_{1}<x_{2}$ and $x_{3}>x_{4}$.

So $x^{2007}_{1}x^{2006}_{4}=x^{2007}_{2}x^{2006}_{3}$ not possible.

Therefore the only possibility is $\displaystyle \frac{A}{2}=\frac{B}{2}.$

So $x_{1}=x_{2}$ and $x_{3}=x_{4}.$

In that case $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles with $\angle ABC=\angle CAB.$ So $AC=BC=1$ unit.